# Keep trailing zeros for percents only

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, pander

Given the following example:

```
library(pander)
tableAbs <- Titanic[1, 1, , ]
tablePct <- round(prop.table(tableAbs) * 100, 2)
table <- cbind(tableAbs, tablePct)
pander(table)

----------------------------------
  &nbsp;     No   Yes   No    Yes 
----------- ---- ----- ----- -----
 **Child**   0     5     0   2.78 

 **Adult**  118   57   65.56 31.67
----------------------------------
```

I would like to keep all trailing zeros on that `0` percentage over there, so this is what I do:

```
panderOptions("keep.trailing.zeros", TRUE)
pander(table)

------------------------------------
  &nbsp;      No    Yes   No    Yes 
----------- ------ ----- ----- -----
 **Child**   0.00  5.00  0.00  2.78 

 **Adult**  118.00 57.00 65.56 31.67
------------------------------------
```

The problem is now that even the absolute frequencies have `.00` attached to them. Since those are natural numbers, it makes little sense to keep *those* trailing zeros. How do I do this?

Comment: I'm not an experienced `r` user, but do you think you could call `gsub` or something on the elements of `table`? If so, this is a piece of cake using a simple [tag:regex].

Comment: Try `tablePct <- format(round(prop.table(tableAbs) * 100, 2))`

Comment: I was going to suggest converting to character (or using `sprintf('%.2f', table)` or whatever) and then reapplying the attributes  to get the structure back, but it seems like that is what format does in one step by preserving the dimensions.

Comment: @rawr, in any case, would you consider writing your solution as an answer so it's more visible?

Comment: @user20650, would you consider writing your solution as an answer so it's more visible?

Comment: @rawr: thats what i did first `tablePct[] <-  sapply(tablePct, sprintf, fmt="%.2f")` .. do you want to write it up .. you have a better understanding of such stuffs

Comment: your idea is more elegant. I just regurgitated what it says under value in `?format`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to rawr in the comments.

You can use `format` to keep the trailing zeros. This converts the rounded values to `character` while preserving the dimensions of the table.

```
tablePct <- format(round(prop.table(tableAbs) * 100, 2))
```

**edit**

Seems to work okay with `xtabs` class

```
mtcars$am[mtcars$vs == 1]  <- 0
x <- xtabs(~ am + vs, data=mtcars)
tab <- format(round(100*prop.table(x), 2))
tab <- cbind(x, tab)
pander(tab)

---------------------------
&nbsp;   0   1    0     1  
------- --- --- ----- -----
 **0**  12  14  37.50 43.75

 **1**   6   0  18.75 0.00 
---------------------------
```

Comment: This does it for the mock data. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work with my real table, which is of the `xtabs` class (and `format` transforms numbers into characters). I'll see if I can work around that.

Comment: Waldir, please feel free to edit your question with an xtabs example

Comment: Thanks, but I got it. Took a little butchering and stiching, but it's finally looking beautiful.